# Is my CTE alternative to ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE to avoid sequence increment safe for concurrent writes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below is the shortened body of a postgres stored function (language sql), that takes "_type_id" & "_group_id" as parameters. It works fine, however I cannot find similar examples online.

I usually use a ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE, however I want to try to avoid the gaps in my primary key sequence. Most examples online show the way to do this is to do an update then an insert where not exists.

Does this have any advantages as its a single statement rather than a separate update then insert if not exists?

Does it being in a stored function make it safe for concurrent writes or that its a single statement? Or is it not safe at all for concurrent writes?

```
 with cte_data as (
    select _type_id
  ),
  cte_update as (
    update group_data gd
    set type_id = d.type_id
    from cte_data d
    where gd.group_id = _group_id
    returning group_id
  )
  insert into group_data(group_id, type_id)
    select _group_id, 
            d.type_id
    from cte_data d
    where not exists(select * from cte_update)
```

Comment: "*however I want to try to avoid the gaps in my primary key sequence.*" - why? Gaps in a sequence are pretty meaningless and nothing to worry about.

Comment: Why not use MERGE instead of separate UPDATE/INSERT statements?

Comment: @NickW: Postgres has not MERGE statement. `INSERT ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` is a (better) alternative - but it might skip sequence values which Will is trying to avoid for some strange reason.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/55920/sql-merge.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Gaps in a sequence should be worried about if the table is updated frequently. I have had issues in production using it where my sequence has hit the int limit for the PK sequence. We get data from various sources that needs updating every 15 minutes, about 100,000 rows in each update but only a couple thousand inserted.
The question really is if there is anything wrong with the CTE approach, can anyone answer if it is safe for concurrent writes or not?

Comment: @Will A sequence generates `bigint` values. Even if you burn 1000 values per second 24/7 it would take 29247120 years to exhaust the sequence. The reference to MERGE is meaningless as Postgres doesn't have a MERGE statement

Comment: @NickW: a mail thread discussing the possible implementation of such a feature is not a reference to the existence of the feature. The only authoritative source if such a statement exists in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for expanding & also clarifying that other link was actually just a mail thread. 
The issue I had was a few months ago "nextval: reached maximum value of sequence \"garage_availability_slots_id_seq\" (2147483647)" for some reason my PK was int not bigint. I will just make sure I am using bigint, but would still be good to know if there's anything inherently wrong with my approach. I fixed that issue a few months ago by removing the sequence as it was a child table & instead using a composite PK over some other columns

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name FWIW Postgres docs are actually showing me the default 'serial' data type is the size of int, you have to use bigserial to get bigint sequences. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: The _sequence_ will always generate `bigint` values. But the `serial` pseudo-type is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) anyway

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you again, I will move to use GENERATED BY DEFAULT/ALWAYS AS IDENTITY instead & stop using serial. If I had been using this I would have never hit the max sequence value as you said. ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE reads cleaner than my CTE suggestion, so I will keep using it instead.